# Reading form elements into the component's property

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am trying to read attribute values of HTML elements such as input tag in angular 2. My preferred way to read it would be to bind the input element with the component property without creating another model class

Two of the solutions that are known to me are :

1) **Using JSON object**: create a reference variable for the form:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)" #loginForm="ngForm">
```

and my  login component will become

```
onSubmit(form:NgForm){
    console.log(form.value);
}
```

**2)** Create a model object and initialize it in the component

```
user=new User();
onSubmit(form:NgForm){
   console.log(user.username); 
}
```

and in the HTML

```html
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" 
            [(ngModel)]="user.username" #username="ngModel"/>
```

But I dont want to use any of the above mentioned approach (don't want to use JSON object NOR want to create model object for every form submitted.. should I ?)

I want to bind component attributes to form directly. So something like this

I want to read what the user has input in the input element username directly into the property of LoginComponent username (focus on the *[(ngModel)]="username"* instead of *[(ngModel)]="user.username"*

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #loginForm="ngForm">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username"     [(ngModel)]="username" #username="ngModel"/>
                {{username}}           
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
 </form>
```

```
@Component({'
.. something
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   username:string;
  onSubmit(){
    console.log(username);
    console.log(user?.username);
  }  
}
```

**EDIT**
I have tried using "this"

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.username);
  }
```

but then the error I got was
zone.js:632 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

```
Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
 Thanks in advance for the help
```

Comment: you should be referring to `this.username`

Comment: I did try it
 onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.username);
 }
I kept my input element as is.
the error I get is  Cannot assign to a reference or variable!